# c# cosmos IndexOf not supported

Tags: c#, vmware, cosmos

I am using cosmos to practice my c# and better my understanding of OS.
I am trying to use a IndexOf method but VMware gives me:

```
Be aware: IndexOf(..., Stringcomparison) not fully supported yet!
```

Are there any alternative for Indexof method?
For example, if my string is "hello@world" i'd like to find that the index of @ is 5.

Comment: You should search the documentation and try to understand if these part not supported are of any relevance to your code

Comment: I googled it, but I could not find anything regarding this.

Comment: Going directly to the source is a way: http://cosmos.codeplex.com/discussions/536735

Comment: I do not still understand.. I made sure types are matched. String find = "@", word = "hello@world"  and I did int index = word.IndexOf(find). But I am still getting the same error. Please help

Comment: @m.k the point is that this is not full C# on Cosmos, but a subset of it that is not fully implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement a similar method yourself.
Such a bare-bone method that returns the index of a char or -1 if wasn't found can be:

```
public int FindIndexOfChar(string str, char c)
{
    for (int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        if (str[i]==c)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

It really depends upon the functionality you want.